# Setting MasterPageFile in Global.asax breaks URL Page Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, master-pages

I am using the `Global.asax` file to override the `Page_PreInit` event to set the `MasterPageFile`, I'm also using `Page Routing`.

It seems that when I set the `MasterPageFile`, it breaks the `PageRouting` and causes a 404 on every URL.

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = this.Context.Handler as Page;
    if (p != null) {
        p.PreInit += new EventHandler(Page_PreInit);
    }
}

void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = this.Context.Handler as Page;
    if (p != null) {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Branding-UseCustomMasterPage"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["Branding-CustomMasterPageName"] != null) {
            if (Boolean.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["Branding-UseCustomMasterPage"].ToString())) {
                if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Valve Steam GameOverlay")) {
                    p.MasterPageFile = "~/APIMasterPages/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["Branding-CustomMasterPageName"].ToString() + "-SteamOverlay.master";
                }
                else {
                    p.MasterPageFile = "~/APIMasterPages/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["Branding-CustomMasterPageName"].ToString() + ".master";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Valve Steam GameOverlay")) {
                p.MasterPageFile = "~/APIMasterPages/SteamOverlay.master";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the code used to set the `PageRoutes` is:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("");

    routes.MapPageRoute("api-initiate", "api-initiate/{apiKey}/", "~/Corporate/APIInitiate.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("404", "{*url}", "~/Page-Not-Found.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all the objects you are trying to pull out of the session null by any chance and you are hitting only the else{} case in the your Page_PreInit()?

Comment: Yes, but even then it will still "p.MasterPageFile = "~/APIMasterPages/SteamOverlay.master";".  Which works fine.  But with enforcing a new master page via this method, it seems to break all of the page routing..

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was; on `Page_Load` I was interacting with the `MasterPage` as such;

```
SiteMaster m = Master as SiteMaster;
```

However, when I changed the `MasterPage` that was in turn causing an error; and the `PageRoute` was sending off to a 404 error.

The fix was to use the actual class I inherit within the MasterPage classes.

```
Custom.CustomMasterPage m = Master as Custom.CustomMasterPage;
```

MasterPage class definition:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : Custom.CustomMasterPage
{ 
    // Master page class   
}
```